# trouble with df.replace in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a set of about 30 columns that I want to convert to int. These columns get pulled in as string dtype but needs to be converted to int.

When I do this

```
df = df[['columns','to','change']].astype(int)
```

I get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '\xe2\x80\xa0'
```

So I want to replace that string with None and then drop NA.  I am trying this.

```
#there are some funky values in some columns that should have numbers.  Lets trash them
starting_row_count = len(df.index)
df.dropna()
current_row_count = len(df.index)
print current_row_count - starting_row_count

def strip_it(value):
   #culls rotten values
    if type(value) == str:
        value.replace('\xe2\x80\xa0', None)
        value.replace('"', None)
        value.replace('=', None) 
    return value

df = df.astype(str)

df = df.apply(strip_it)

df.dropna()
current_row_count = len(df.index)
print current_row_count - starting_row_count
```

Both print statements produce 0, showing no rows are removed.

I would hope this would remove those values from my DF but I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you should use the first few rows, so we can reproduce this?

Comment: `df.dropna()` - return copy of the dataframe if you'd like to do it inplace you need to pass argument inplace: `df.dropna(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

value.replace is incorrect.

.replace acts on a series or a dataframe, but not an individual value.

thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html):

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

And it'll change all non-numeric values to NaN automatic

**EDIT**
I've got a warning while I'm doing that way:

> FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

So you could use [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [pd.to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) methods:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))
```